# ckeditor tabSpaces not working in bulleted list java

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I have put "config.tabSpaces = 4;" to configCKEditor, and I can make tabs in usual text.
But if I create bulleted list and try to make tab after some text in second point, sublist is created, but I want just a tab.

first -

[image: i]

result -

[image: i]

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces + PF Extensions are you using?

Comment: I use: 6.1 + 6.1.1

Comment: It may possibly just be CKEDITOR default behavior?  I know if Microsoft Word if you start bulleted list and Tab it does the exact same thing. See the plugin it confirms TAB and SHIFT+TAB indent: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/indentlist

Comment: Yes it is default behavior, but I need to change it. And I don't know how

Comment: Probably a question for the CKEditor forums.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "built-in" feature into CKEditor. The list indentation on tab key is handled by [indentlist plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/indentlist) which is [required by the list plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/list/plugin.js#L848) which means that you can't remove it if you want to use lists inside CKEditor.